# Do 1.5% of lithium-ion batteries overheat, explode, or catch fire each year?

Tags: safety, fire, battery

According to [Gitnux](https://gitnux.org/lithium-ion-battery-fire-statistics/):

> “Every year, 1.5% of lithium-ion batteries are linked to overheating, explosion, or fire incidents.”

On the face of it, this is worrying—especially since overheating may go unnoticed and lead, via thermal degradation in a positive-feedback loop, to conflagration. (Li-ion batteries generally do not explode; but they do burn with great intensity.)

Does anyone know of an authoritative source for this? My guess is that the 1.5% has been overstated by a huge factor: perhaps a thousandfold.

Comment: Just had a look at a random other page on Gitnux. https://gitnux.org/candy-crush-statistics/. The paragraphs read like they were written by ChatGPT. Also at the bottom of this page the FAQ also mentions frequency of battery fires, and contradicts the line you quote.

Comment: Yup: https://gitnux.org/editorial-process/ *Our internal algorithm organizes these statistics into themes* ... *The articles are created using our internal database, with the assistance of artificial intelligence and our editors*. IOW a human might have looked at it before it gets published.

Comment: If that's true, given the number of lithium batteries in my house I'm surprised I've survived this long.

Comment: The good news (grin) is that other bots will read that page, "learn" that, and report it as true in turn. "AI" is getting closer and closer to mankind, capable of repeating false information without any discrimination.

Comment: On a side-note, to reduce the risk of fire, use the charger that came with your device (or one designed for it.)  Chargers are not always interchangeable.  This goes for USB-C as well (infuriatingly.)

Comment: That isn't even a claim yet because the number 1.5% is meaningless without a methodology.  Is one CR123A battery counted the same as an entire EV battery pack?

Comment: "overheating" seems a bit undefined - guessing they've included any time a battery gets excessively warm while charging.

Comment: My phone and its lithium-ion battery probably "overheat" (maybe 45–50°C) every day at least briefly especially during charging. I suspect many others have the same problem. But such "overheating" is a long way off from exploding or catching fire. Lumping together "overheating, explosion, and fire incidents" is a bit like lumping together "petty theft, murder, and mass shootings".

Comment: @jcaron We're transitioning from the Information Age to the Misinformation Age.

Answer (score 71):

> On the face of it, this is worrying ...

On the face of it, this statistic is ridiculous, and it does not jibe with other statistics on the same page. The web page also claims

> In 2020, the US Consumer Product Safety Commission reported an average of one battery fire every two days in the U.S.

In 2019, there were [360 million personal devices in the U.S.](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/cell-phones-by-country), almost all of which used lithium-ion batteries. (This number has only grown since then). That corresponds to 0.00005%, not 1.5%. About [270 people in the U.S. are struck by lightning every year](https://www.britannica.com/question/What-are-the-chances-of-being-struck-by-lightning), which is more than one every other day. You have a greater chance of being struck by lightning than having your cellphone's battery catch on fire.

Note also that this 1.5% statistic bunches together "overheating, explosion, or fire incidents." Leave your cellphone flashlight on and put it in your pocket (or butt dial the flashlight while the cellphone is in your pocket) and it will get slightly warm. Strictly speaking, that's an overheating event. I myself have butt dialed my cellphone's flashlight, and yes, my cellphone got warmish. Conflating overheating events, the vast majority of which are mild, with explosions and fires makes for a highly dubious statistic.

I'll next look at electric vehicles. [IEEE Spectrum](https://spectrum.ieee.org/lithium-ion-battery-fires) reports that

> In the United States, according to a 2023 study citing recent data from the National Transportation Safety Board and the Bureau of Transportation Statistics, gasoline-powered, internal-combustion engine (ICE) cars were involved in about 1,530 fires per every 100,000 sold. On the other hand, pure electric vehicles (meaning those powered only by batteries) were involved in just 25 fires per 100,000 sold.

The IEEE Spectrum article goes on to look at statistics from Sweden where 40% of the new vehicles are now EVs. The IEEE Spectrum article reports

> that in 2022, there were only 24 EV car fires in Sweden, representing 0.004 percent of battery-powered cars there. For cars running on gasoline or diesel fuel, the fire rate was 0.08 percent, or 20 times the frequency.

Comment: This already answers the question nicely, but maybe point out the information about the source uncovered in the comments, i.e. that the source is a click-mill based on LLM?

Comment: If I charge my phone and it gets hot, is that an overheating event?

Comment: @Nobody First off, it doesn't really whether it was a human or an AI that pulled a statistic out of thin air. It was pulled out of thin air, period. Secondly, the question as written by the OP doesn't address that issue. That was a comment that I did not feel at all compelled to address.

Comment: @Nelson Who knows? The author of the blog in question did not clarify the meaning of "overheating". There are several other "statistics" on that page that are highly dubious, for example that "48% of cell phone fires are caused by lithium-ion batteries." I suspect that the correct statistic is well into the 90th percentile. Cellphones do catch on fire (extremely rarely, but it does happen). In the very rare events where they do catch on fire, it's almost always the battery that is to blame. The 48% is a made-up statistic -- as is the 1.5% statistic.

Comment: A _lot_ of the page is actually concerned with fires at waste plants. The website is very unclear, so I'm not going to make any excuses for them, but actually I wonder whether they're referring to batteries discarded in landfill or other waste treatment facilities. Firstly, the batteries shouldn't be there in the first place (so that massively reduces the pool of candidate batteries to combust) and secondly, I could imagine a battery being smashed around in a processing facility could be expected to pose the level of risk they state. Still, badly worded, even if that is the intended  context

Comment: @roganjosh A lot of discarded batteries don't even make it to the waste plant: [A vape battery the size of an adult's thumb caused a recycling collection truck to catch fire in Melville](https://hamilton.govt.nz/your-council/news/community-environment/truck-fire-caused-by-vape-battery)

Comment: Your link on "360 million personal devices in the U.S." points to a page which gives statistics only for cell phones (and has two different figures for the US). The total number of devices with Lithium batteries is likely a lot larger than that, once you include laptops, tablets, wireless headsets, power banks, some remote controls, cars, key fobs, e-cigarettes, electric toothbrushes, razors, and probably a ton of other devices which just don't come to mind, so the percentage is even lower.

Comment: imagine 6 million passengers on airlines per day and they only ask you to switch to airplane mode, at this level there would be fires every single day

Comment: Did they count fire engines which are without doubt involved in many fires?

Comment: For anyone looking for the "24 EV fires in 2022 in Sweden" source, the **IEEE Spectrum** is quoting **thecooldown.com**, who is quoting **warpnews.org** with a dead link. Googling an updated link reveals warpnews.org is quoting a Swedish newspaper **DN.se** with a paywall...